Are the 2 power sources connected inside this IC?
If I connect a USB power source to the IN1, OV1, and PR1 pins of the TPS2121, and another power source with a large capacitance (e.g., 200 µF, exceeding the 10 µF limit imposed by USB specifications) to the IN2, OV2, and PR2 pins, should I be concerned that the large capacitance on the second power source will interfere with or affect the USB connection? Or are the two inputs isolated from each other within the TPS2121?
TPS2121 Functional Block Diagram from the datasheet:

My schematic:


A multiplexer selects exactly one of the sources.
And even if both sources were enabled, the current limit and reverse current protection would prevent the large capacitor from having a noticeable effect.
